# No type named 'u16string' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using QT 5.5.0.

When I compile a program, it shows “no type named 'u16string' in namespace 'std'”. The interesting part is that I compiled it successfully in the past, why is it failing now? It seems to be trouble with `qstring.h`.

How do I fix it? Here is where the error happen

```
#ifndef QSTRING_H 
#define QSTRING_H 
#if defined(QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII) && defined(QT_RESTRICTED_CAST_FROM_ASCII) 
#error QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII and QT_RESTRICTED_CAST_FROM_ASCII must not be defined at the same time 
#endif 

#include <QtCore/qchar.h> 
#include <QtCore/qbytearray.h> 
#include <QtCore/qrefcount.h>
#include <QtCore/qnamespace.h> 
#include <string> 
#if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID)
// std::wstring is disabled on android's glibc, as bionic lacks certain features 
// that libstdc++ checks for (like mbcslen). namespace std { typedef basic_string<wchar_t> wstring; }
#endif

#if defined(Q_COMPILER_UNICODE_STRINGS) || defined(Q_QDOC) 
   static inline QString fromStdU16String(const std::u16string &s); 
   inline std::u16string toStdU16String() const; 
   static inline QString fromStdU32String(const std::u32string &s); 
   inline std::u32string toStdU32String() const; 
#endif
```

Comment: It would be useful if you post your code, please

Comment: @PaoloM #if defined(Q_COMPILER_UNICODE_STRINGS) || defined(Q_QDOC)     static inline QString fromStdU16String(const std::u16string &s);     inline std::u16string toStdU16String() const;     static inline QString fromStdU32String(const std::u32string &s);     inline std::u32string toStdU32String() const; #endif

Comment: Have you included `<string>`? It would be helpfull to see more code. Maybe edit your question instead of posting the code as a comment.

Comment: @muXXmit2X the code is too long,which has about 1500 lows.

Comment: @shengfuzou Well, as `u16string` is defined in the c++ header `string` you need to include that header. Be sure to have the line `#include <string>` in the file where you use `u16string`

Comment: @ecatmur it should be clang

Comment: @muXXmit2X yes, I have

Comment: @shengfuzou Have you enabled the c++11 features while compiling? I guess using clang it was something like `-std=c++11`

Comment: #ifndef QSTRING_H #define QSTRING_H  #if defined(QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII) && defined(QT_RESTRICTED_CAST_FROM_ASCII) #error QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII and QT_RESTRICTED_CAST_FROM_ASCII must not be defined at the same time #endif  #include <QtCore/qchar.h> #include <QtCore/qbytearray.h> #include <QtCore/qrefcount.h> #include <QtCore/qnamespace.h>  #include <string>  #if defined(Q_OS_ANDROID) // std::wstring is disabled on android's glibc, as bionic lacks certain features // that libstdc++ checks for (like mbcslen). namespace std {     typedef basic_string<wchar_t> wstring; } #endif

Comment: @ecatmur + demonplus: I'm experiencing this same issue when using OSX 10.10.5 (Yosemite), Qt Creator 3.6.0 (IDE), Clang 6.0 64-bit (compiler), Qt 5.5.0/5.5.1, QMake, and C++14.  There is no issue when I use Windows 7 and MingW+GCC.  Interestingly, there is no issue compiling when I use C++11 (which shengfu was using), but this leads to another issue which is probably unrelated:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243888/why-cant-clang-find-the-project-directory-for-this-qt-project-when-building-on

Answer (score 7):

To fix it:

1. as the Qt on mac is built by clang, in "Qt Creator" -> "Preferences" -> "Kits", you should set "Compiler" to clang.
2. instead of writing "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11", add below config to your .pro file:

   ```
   CONFIG += c++11
   ```

https://forum.qt.io/topic/56064/solved-problem-with-qt-5-5/11

Answer (score 0):

> The interesting part is that I compiled it successfully in the past, why is it failing now?

Earlier you would have included some library's header which in turn included `<string>`; this, after some update perhaps, would've stopped including it directly and thus the error.

> How to fix it?

Include the proper header in your source to avoid these kind of issues.

```
#include <string>
```

in the [translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1106149/183120) where the error occurs and make sure you're referring to it with the namespace: `std::u16string`.

Comment: Normally this would work, but it doesn't help in shengfu's case.  The failure is in the Qt library itself in a header file called qstring.h.  Including <string> in all of his own header files won't change anything.  Interestingly, <string> is included in the faulty header file (as shown in the code copied into the question), but the problem persists anyway when std::u16string is referenced (also shown in the code).  I'm not sure what the real cause is as I'm struggling with the same issue myself.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the file ExpGame.pro.I delete code as bellow:

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

And it is OK.

Comment: This removes support for C++11, so you won't be able to use any C++11 features.  I don't feel that this is a good final solution.