# Why doesn't Clang generate the TARGET directory for this Qt project when building on OSX?

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, c++11, clang

I have a project ([full code here](http://github.com/nthexwn/AISweeper)) that uses the following toolchain:

- OSX 10.10.5 (Yosemite)
- C++11 (still seems to have better compiler support than C++14)
- Qt 5.5.0 (cross-platform GUI library)
- Qt Creator 3.5.0 (IDE which is tightly integrated with Qt)
- QMake (build tool which is tightly integrated with Qt)
- Clang 6.0 64-bit (default compiler when using Qt Creator on OSX)
- Xcode 6.1.1 (another IDE for OSX which Clang appears to be bundled with)

The problem occurs when I attempt to build the project.  It's worth noting that the exact same code and project file compile and link without any errors or warnings when I use Windows 7 instead of OSX and MingW/GCC instead of Xcode/Clang.  It's also worth noting that this exact same toolset was working a few commits ago when I was last developing on my OSX machine.  If I had to guess, I'd say adding the "CONFIG += c++11" line to my project file is what triggered the issue (unable to remove this now without causing other issues).  Here is an example of the output:

```
09:06:44: Running steps for project AISweeper...
09:06:44: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" clean
rm -f qrc_sweeper_resources.cpp
rm -f moc_player_abstract.cpp moc_player_human.cpp moc_player_machine_learning_ai.cpp moc_player_probability_based_ai.cpp moc_player_random_action_ai.cpp moc_sweeper_batch_manager.cpp moc_sweeper_batch_settings.cpp moc_sweeper_batch_status.cpp moc_sweeper_control_window.cpp moc_sweeper_game.cpp moc_sweeper_widget.cpp
rm -f ui_sweeper_control_window.h
rm -f player_abstract.o player_human.o player_machine_learning_ai.o player_probability_based_ai.o player_random_action_ai.o sweeper_batch_manager.o sweeper_batch_settings.o sweeper_batch_status.o sweeper_common_functions.o sweeper_control_window.o sweeper_game.o sweeper_main.o sweeper_model.o sweeper_node.o sweeper_widget.o qrc_sweeper_resources.o moc_player_abstract.o moc_player_human.o moc_player_machine_learning_ai.o moc_player_probability_based_ai.o moc_player_random_action_ai.o moc_sweeper_batch_manager.o moc_sweeper_batch_settings.o moc_sweeper_batch_status.o moc_sweeper_control_window.o moc_sweeper_game.o moc_sweeper_widget.o
rm -f *~ core *.core
09:06:44: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
09:06:44: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
09:06:44: Starting: "/usr/bin/make"
/Users/alexjohnson/Qt/5.5/clang_64/bin/uic ../AISweeper/ui/sweeper_control_window.ui -o ui_sweeper_control_window.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../AISweeper -I. -I../../../Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I../../../Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I../../../Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I../../../Qt/5.5/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/Users/alexjohnson/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib -o player_abstract.o ../AISweeper/src/players/player_abstract.cpp
   *snip*
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../AISweeper -I. -I../../../Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I../../../Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I../../../Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I../../../Qt/5.5/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/Users/alexjohnson/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib -o moc_sweeper_game.o moc_sweeper_game.cpp
/Users/alexjohnson/Qt/5.5/clang_64/bin/moc -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -D__APPLE__ -D__GNUC__=4 -D__APPLE_CC__ -I/Users/alexjohnson/Qt/5.5/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -I/Users/alexjohnson/WORKSPACE_ASJ/GitHub/AISweeper -I/Users/alexjohnson/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Users/alexjohnson/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Users/alexjohnson/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -F/Users/alexjohnson/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib ../AISweeper/inc/sweeper_widget.h -o moc_sweeper_widget.cpp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../AISweeper -I. -I../../../Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I../../../Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I../../../Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I../../../Qt/5.5/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/Users/alexjohnson/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib -o moc_sweeper_widget.o moc_sweeper_widget.cpp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-syslibroot,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Wl,-rpath,/Users/alexjohnson/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib -o AISweeper.app/Contents/MacOS/AISweeper AISweeper player_abstract.o player_human.o player_machine_learning_ai.o player_probability_based_ai.o player_random_action_ai.o sweeper_batch_manager.o sweeper_batch_settings.o sweeper_batch_status.o sweeper_common_functions.o sweeper_control_window.o sweeper_game.o sweeper_main.o sweeper_model.o sweeper_node.o sweeper_widget.o qrc_sweeper_resources.o moc_player_abstract.o moc_player_human.o moc_player_machine_learning_ai.o moc_player_probability_based_ai.o moc_player_random_action_ai.o moc_sweeper_batch_manager.o moc_sweeper_batch_settings.o moc_sweeper_batch_status.o moc_sweeper_control_window.o moc_sweeper_game.o moc_sweeper_widget.o   -F/Users/alexjohnson/Qt/5.5/clang_64/lib -stdlib=libc++ -framework QtWidgets -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework AGL
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'AISweeper'
make: *** [AISweeper.app/Contents/MacOS/AISweeper] Error 1
09:07:03: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project AISweeper (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
09:07:03: Elapsed time: 00:19.
```

I'm having a hard time interpreting all of this, but I believe this means Clang is failing to find the 'AISweeper' directory inside the generated app while linking (hence all the .o files mentioned).  This seems to be controlled by the TARGET variable in the QMake project file.  If I change this variable from 'AISweeper' to 'Foo' then it fails to find the 'Foo' directory.  After manually checking the generated app I can confirm that "/Users/alexjohnson/WORKSPACE_ASJ/GitHub/build-AISweeper-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_clang_64bit-Debug/AISweeper.app/Contents/MacOS/" exists, but that there is no 'AISweeper' directory inside of it.  I'm not sure how to ensure it exists as part of the build process.  I've also tried abandoning Clang and switching to GCC, but this led to incompatibility issues between C++11, OSX, and Qt.  I've tried Googling the issue, but most of the time this error seems to occur when Clang can't find third party libraries.  In my case it can't seem to find my project directory itself.  I did see some mention of opening the project in Xcode and modifying some settings there, but I couldn't open my project directly with Xcode or find any of the settings mentioned.  Here are the contents of my QMake project file (AISweeper.pro) in case there's something else I should try modifying in here:

```
CONFIG += \
c++11

FORMS += \
ui/sweeper_control_window.ui

HEADERS += \
inc/players/player_abstract.h \
inc/players/player_human.h \
inc/players/player_machine_learning_ai.h \
inc/players/player_probability_based_ai.h \
inc/players/player_random_action_ai.h \
inc/sweeper_batch_manager.h \
inc/sweeper_batch_settings.h \
inc/sweeper_batch_status.h \
inc/sweeper_common_functions.h \
inc/sweeper_control_window.h \
inc/sweeper_game.h \
inc/sweeper_model.h \
inc/sweeper_node.h \
inc/sweeper_widget.h

QT += \
core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

LIBS += \
-stdlib=libc++

RESOURCES += \
rsc/sweeper_resources.qrc

SOURCES += \
src/players/player_abstract.cpp \
src/players/player_human.cpp \
src/players/player_machine_learning_ai.cpp \
src/players/player_probability_based_ai.cpp \
src/players/player_random_action_ai.cpp \
src/sweeper_batch_manager.cpp \
src/sweeper_batch_settings.cpp \
src/sweeper_batch_status.cpp \
src/sweeper_common_functions.cpp \
src/sweeper_control_window.cpp \
src/sweeper_game.cpp \
src/sweeper_main.cpp \
src/sweeper_model.cpp \
src/sweeper_node.cpp \
src/sweeper_widget.cpp

TARGET += \
AISweeper

TEMPLATE += \
app
```

What else can I try doing to resolve this?  I just want these tools to play nice with each other and my project to build so I can get back to coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing "TARGET +=" to "TARGET =" in my project file.  This seemed so strange that I re-included the '+' character, cleaned, and rebuilt the project to make sure that the '+' character had really caused the issue.  It started failing again.  I removed it a second time, cleaned, and rebuilt again.  It started working again.

As I mentioned in the question this has been working on my Windows machine without any changes ('+' character included).

I don't fully understand the QMake process, but it seems that at some point Clang must be trying to parse the project file itself and fails in a way that GCC does not.  One would think that all of the variables in the project file would be treated the same way (IE: you can use += to add to them, even if there's only a single entry), but there appears to be something strange in the way the TARGET variable is treated specifically.  This may be a bug in either Clang or Qt Creator, but I can't be certain, so I'm not going to report anything yet.

I'd be quite interested in hearing a deeper explanation for this behavior!